# Setting NSStatusItem Tooltip from a different Object

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a NSStatusItem called statusItem created in my AppDelegate. I want to change the tooltip in the instance of NSStatusItem in a different object, but don't know how to do so since I'm still getting the hang of the Objective C language coming from Basic.

How should I implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, add a method to the AppDelegate:

```
-(void)setStatusToolTip:(NSString*)toolTip
{
    [statusItem setToolTip:toolTip];
}
```

Now, in the other object from which you want to change the tooltip, do this:

```
AppDelegate* appDelegate=[NSApp delegate];
[appDelegate setStatusToolTip:@"new tool tip!"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider moving the status item creation and ownership from the app delegate to the object that needs to set its tooltip.

Comment: The problem with moving the StatusItem creation is that I would have to move everything else, which becomes a big mess. I want to keep the API interaction related functions separate from the graphical stuff (Window, Status Item, Preference Windows, etc).